# Render an array of objects in mustache js

Tags: javascript, arrays, mustache

```
[Object, Object]
    0: Object
        0: Object
        id: 1
        name: "xvxvxcv"
        semester: 2
    1: Object
```

How can I render this array of objects in mustache js? I can't use `{{#data}}` `{{/data}}` to iterate because it hasn't a name.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Object, Object]
    0: Object
        0: Object
        id: 1
        name: "xvxvxcv"
        semester: 2
    1: Object
```

Probably this is the output shown in JS Console. You got the output by simply entering a variable. Of course, you must have assigned the object to the variable. When you have a variable assigned to an object, you can directly access the variable in mustache code something like this,

```
{{#object}}
  {{key}} : {{value}}
{{/object}}
```